# dns with Round-robin a two web servers

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server

i have two webservers and the next zone

```
web1.example.org IN A 10.0.0.1
web2.example.org IN A 10.0.0.2

example.org IN CNAME web1.example.org
example.org IN CNAME web2.example.org
```

The problem its the php session, you go to web1.example.org and later the dns responds web2.example.org.

How can i fix this?

Comment: I'm probably being anal-retentive, and this doesn't have anything to do with your issue, but you can't have a CNAME as the root of a domain. RFC 1034 specifies that a CNAME can't be shared with any RR having the same name, including NS records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either need a persistent session store that's not on either server's local disk (e.g. a database or a network volume) or you need to ditch the round-robin approach and implement a load balancer intelligent enough to keep sending each client to the same server in the cluster.

Round-robin is a bad idea for availability anyway -- if one server fails, you're redirecting half of your traffic to a dead system.

Comment: Round robin balancing to a pair of load-balancers is slightly less bad, though.

Comment: That's yet another point of failure -- you want to at least make sure the IPs are either multicast or high-availability vIPs.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the load to be evenly spread across your servers I would suggest configuring the TTL based on your users sessions to ensure that connections will most likely stay pointed at any given web server.